# Write a function that takes a matrix and a scalar multiplier as input and returns a new matrix containing the scalar product of the scalar and matrix

Tags: python, matrix

> Write a function called `scalar_matrix_multiply` that takes a matrix (represented by a list of numerical lists) and a scalar multiplier (a float) as input and returns a new matrix containing the scalar product of the scalar and the matrix. For example,
>
> ```
> >>scalar_matrix_multiply([[4, 2], [-5,1]], 3)
> [[12, 6], [-15, 3]
> ```

My code:

```
L = 2
def scalar_matrix_multiply(lst, x):
    for i in range(L):
        for j in range(L):
            lst[i][j] = lst[i][j] * x
```

Comment: what is your question/problem?

Comment: I'm trying to solve this question and that's like the code I have atm but it's saying that I am getting it wrong so my question what am I doing wrong? why is my code wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a return statement (i.e. `return lst`). You can also use a list comprehension to avoid reassignments.

```py
def scalar_matrix_multiply(lst, x):
    return [[c * x for c in row] for row in lst]

print(scalar_matrix_multiply([[4, 2], [-5,1]], 3))
```

result:

```
[[12, 6], [-15, 3]]
```

Comment: Glad to help, please "accept" working answers :)